# SageMath: Best way to determine the number of reducible polynomials in a field?

Tags: sage

Suppose I have the polynomial `f(x) = x^n + x + a`.
I set a value for `n`, and want `0 <= a <= A`, where `A` is some other value I set. This means I will have a total of `A` different polynomials, since `a` can be any value between `0` and `A`.

Using Sage, I want find the number of these `A` polynomials that are reducible. For example, suppose I set `n=2` and `A=10^6`. I want to be able to determine how many of these `10^6` polynomials are reducible. Can I please have help constructing a Sage process to do this? **Note:** Sage has the `is_irreducible()` method, but I don't know how to apply it here since I have a lot of polynomials to call the method on.

I was initially thinking of just looping `A` times and incrementing a count but I feel like there has to be a more efficient way to do this? If I did it this way, it would take a really long time for the large values of A that I need like 10^6.

Comment: You should try it. With a simple loop checking for irreducibility of `x^2+x+a`, 10^6 iterations takes 18 seconds on my computer.

Answer (score 0):

A naive approach:

```
sage: F = GF(next_prime(10^6))
sage: R.<x> = F[] # replace F with your favorite field
sage: def count(A):
....:     c = 0
....:     for a in range(A):
....:         if not (x^2+x+a).is_irreducible():
....:             c += 1
....:     return c
....: 
sage: count(10^4)
5031
sage: count(10^5)
50066
sage: %time count(10^6)
CPU times: user 13.2 s, sys: 5.15 ms, total: 13.2 s
Wall time: 13.2 s
500000
```

The speed will probably vary tremendously depending on the field.

You can also add an optional argument to `count`— `def count(A, n=2):` — and then change the polynomial to `x^n+x+a`. Using `n=8` is 2 or 3 times slower than using `n=2`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. What are you doing with the first two lines of code? They don't seem to have an implication in the rest of the script there. Also, for example, when you call `count(10^4)`, is that saying that 5031 of the 10000 polynomials are reducible? Because that definitely isn't right.

Comment: I've managed to make it work for me, but it's taking an extremely long time for values of A like 10^7 and n = 5. Is there a way to speed it up?

Comment: In the first two lines I'm defining the polynomial ring in which I'm working, and in particular defining the symbol `x`. Why isn't it right that 5031 of the 10000 polynomials, with coefficients in Z/1000003, are reducible?